# How return List<string>[] in a web service method

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, return

I want to return `List<string>[]` in a web service and use that return in a windows form like below :

```
    [WebMethod]
    public List<string>[] MyMethod()
    {
       ...
       ...

        List<string>[] list_ar = new List<string>[]{list_optgroup, list_option, list_optgroup_option};

        return list_ar;
    }
```

but on the windows form side I should get that return value like this :

```
        MyService_Soft service = new MyService_Soft();
        string[][] str_ar = service.MyMethod();
```

What is going on and how can I get that `List<string>[]` on the windows form side?

Also it seems like I have an error in these lines :

```
        MyService_Soft service = new MyService_Soft();
        string[][] str_ar = service.FillComboBoxes();
```

**Error :**

> Unable to automatically step into the server. Connecting to the server
>   machine 'blablabla' failed.unknown user name or bad password...

What does this error mean and how can I figure out what line in that web service causes this error?

Comment: How does the error relate to lists at all?  It looks like an authentication issue.

Comment: There is nothing such as a `List<string>[]`. You either want an array like `strings[]` or a list like `List<string>`.

Comment: Does string[][] str_ar = service.MyMethod(); compile for you? MyMethod returns an array of lists not an array of string arrays

Comment: There is nothing such as a List<string>[] -> so how can i return 3 List<string> on that method?

Comment: Try this site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65004e38.aspx

For instance, do you have debug set to "true" in your web.config file?

Comment: @AndreCalil @MoonLight `List<string>[]` is an array of `List<string>`. `new List<string>[]{ new List<string>{ "Hello World" } }`. It is perfectly legal C#.

Comment: @MoonLight, you could try, List<List<string>> whyWouldYouEverDoThis = new List<List<string>>(); or string[][]

Comment: `Romoku` don't you mean something like this instead.. `var someListArray =  new List<string>[]{ new List<string>{ "Hello World" } };` what you have as your example is improper syntax

Comment: too many types > a bit confused :)

Comment: Oh man, mind blow. Why don't you create a class that represents the exact return you mean to give? Array of list strings containing whatever is like hell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no bad errors. You can't debug 2 processes simultaneously from one debugging process. Since server code is running in separate process, you can't step-into it.

To debug server code, open another instance of MS Visual studio (or whatever IDE you use) with server project source code, and go to menu Debug -> Attach to process, then find your server service hosting process and click "Attach".

As for returning string[][] instead of List[] - it is also expected behaviour as client application doesn't know the type of returned collection - the proxy class is autogenerated based on WSDL file. Actually you can change it to use List<> instead of array. Considering WCF service, open WCF SErvice reference properties and select the type of collections (by default array, but can be changed to List in you desire).
But I see no reasons to require to get List instead of array. **The only difference is that List is mutable.** *You shouldn't logically want to have ability to change the returned collection!* **You'd better create a new collection, based on the returned array and modify it instead.**

**UPDATE: Code request.**

The code for the last and main recommendation is really very straight forward:

```
public List<string>[] SomeClientBuilsenessLogicMethod()
{
    var serviceClient = GetServiceClientInstance(); //you might want to have single instance (single connection) of WCF service client, so I implemented it's creation as factory method here.

    string[][] serviceData = serviceClient.MyMethod();

    List<string>[] mutableDataList = serviceData.Select(x=>x.ToList()).ToArray();//Not the best memory usage here probably (better is a loop), but for not big data lists it's fine.

    //Perform any needed operations for list changing. Again there is NO NEED to use List if you don't plan to add/remove items to/from that collection.

    return mutableDataList;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer / would please show some codes for return ? (i do n't want any change in WCF service reference)